# LC filter calculation

Tags: schematics, passive-filter

I need to calculate the L and C values for the filter shown in the below image.
[image]

Vout1 and Vout2 are 70MHz singled ended signals. These will be converted to differential signals through the single to the differential converter.

I know that this is a low pass configuration and the cutoff frequency is 70MHz.

How to calculate the L and C values?

Can I simulate this filter design in simulation tools and verify?

Comment: Yes you can simulate and taylor the filter response to your requirements. Don't forget to simulate the source and load impedances in-circuit to ensure the best outcome. Then if you're game drop in some accurate SPICE models for the passive components etc.

Comment: @citizen How can I calculate the L and C values?

Comment: 2 of those are pi filters used to limit bandwidth and provide a controlled and matched impedance to the LTC6403. Without knowledge of the bandwidth you require, you cannot calculate the values effectively. It's not enough to know that the centre frequency will be 70 MHz. Also, without knowing the source impedance of Vout1 or Vout2 you can't get to proper values.

Comment: @Andyaka You mean the Bandwidth of the Vout1 and Vout2?

Comment: I'm talking about those bandwidths, yes.

Comment: [Low pass \$\pi\$ matching calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20PI%20LP.html).

Comment: @Andyaka The bandwidth of the Vout1 and Vout2 will 0-50Mhz

Comment: Bandwidth isn't a range it's a single limiting value for this case. I recommend you use a simulator and follow the calculations in the link I gave.